# Char Pointers and malloc

Tags: c, pointers, char, malloc, cs50

I was a bit confused with the concept of char pointers so I made a simple code just printing my name provided by user (me). I also wanted to practice malloc so I referenced the pointer to a certain memory in RAM, but I really didn't know what to put after "sizeof(char) *" because that is the user input, which is not yet decided. 
Also, after doing that, I freed the memory, but I got an error message on command line saying:

```
*** Error in `./char': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00000000017fe030 ***
Aborted
```

It seems like I freed the same memory twice or something, but I don't know what to delete or add. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{

    char *strings = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);


    printf("What is your name?\n");

    //wait for use to type his/her name
    strings = get_string();


    printf("Hello %s\n", strings);

    free (strings);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is get_string ? Is it C language defined ? You should pass the allocated memory to get string and in there fill the array. Not overwriting. Please add the code of `get_string`

Comment: According to https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/21617/whats-the-c-equivalent-for-string-input-getstring answer, `cs50.h` has the function name is `GetString()` not `get_string()`.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with running that, just a memory leak. Did you copy and paste it or retype it?

Comment: @rsp According to the [CS50 reference](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string), it is `get_string`. I think that poster misspelled it.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone trying to answer, add the information that `get_string` returns a `char*` allocated with `malloc` to the question. Not many will hunt down the CS50 documentation and check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory is allocated at the statement:
 `strings = get_string();`

You dont  have to `malloc` it (    `char *strings = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);`
)

Without `malloc` it will work fine

Answer (score 6):

The line `strings = get_string();` actually assigns the value returned by `get_string()` to `strings`. It doesn't write it into the memory you allocated.

So the value returne by `malloc()` has been overwritten (and lost in this case).

The `free(strings)` is releasing whatever `get_string()` returned. The question doesn't provide the code for that but presumably it isn't valid to `free()` it.

Because the run-time told you it was freed twice I'm guessing you have allocated memory in `get_string()` then freed it and returned an invalid pointer.

If you want to use the memory you allocated you need to change `get_string()` to accept a pointer:

```
void get_string(char *str){
    //Do whatever writing you value into str[] as an array of char..
}
```

Good practice would have:

```
void get_string(char *str, size_t max){
    //Do whatever writing you value into str[] as an array of char..
    //Use max to avoid writing beyond the end of the space allocated...
}
```

Then call as `get_string(strings,10);`.

**EDIT:** After a bit of research the flaw has been identified. `get_string()` doesn't directly `free()` the string it returns but adds it to a list of allocations made by the library which are freed on exit (in a function called `teardown()` registered with `atexit()` or other compiler dependent features).

That is poor design because consumer code is provided no safe way of itself freeing the memory which in a typical use case will not be required for the whole application execution. `get_double()` is worse because it never returns the allocated data but never reuses it and amounts to a straight memory leak.

The code should either:

1. Conform to the documentation and require consumer code to `free()` the string (maybe rename it as say `get_string_alloc()` for clarity).
2. Offer a library routine to free the string (`get_new_string()` and `release_string()`)

There is no very nice way to shift ownership of allocated memory in C but holding onto it for the remainder of execution is definitely not the answer.
Many libraries go round the houses to push allocation onto consumer code but that is onerous when the full size of the space required can't be known such as here.

I'd suggest putting `_alloc()` at the end of any function that returns objects that consumer code must later `free()`.

So the answer for the question posed is remove the `malloc()` and the `free()` because the library handles both. However beware if your program makes many calls to that function and others that internally rely on it (like `get_double()`) you may run out of memory because the library is sitting on dead space.

Comment: "presumably it isn't valid to free() it." - [unfortunately, it *is* valid](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string). I continue to harbor my utmost desire to throttle the fiends that devised the `cs50.h` library, for multiple reasons including, but not limited to, `typedef char *string;` That right there should tell you how inglorious that header is.

Comment: @WhozCraig Then I think there may a problem in the cs50 code. You shouldn't be doing the `malloc()` because the docco says it allocates the space. But just because your code leaks 10 bytes shouldn't result in a message saying you've double freed something. It might just issue an error at the end of execution that a block of 10 bytes wasn't freed.
Where did you get the code from? Can you post the source for `get_string()`?

Comment: Apparently, depending on the version of cs50 you use, the [library may manage its own chain of heap allocations from `get_string`](https://github.com/cs50/libcs50/blob/develop/docs/get_string.adoc), and free them on process exit (pointless save for good practice, as the OS will reclaim all that memory regardless). In doing that, a double-free will certainly ensue if also done in the users code. Different versions of the library don't do that. So someone following an old tutorial would write code that, using a newer lib, would incur a double-free. That may be what happened here.

Comment: @WhozCraig I poked around on github and saw a version doing that. It's madness. Are you obliged to use this?

Comment: Some students taking courses from schools choosing to use that lib as part of their part of their introductory curriculum are, unfortunately, obliged to use it. It's really too bad too, because many of the things this "helpful" lib do would be excellent remedial candidates as tasks for people being taught the language to do as assignments. Seriously. `get_int`, `get_string`, etc, would all be worthwhile ways for people to learn the language, and the standard library.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've amended the answer because we now have the full reason why you get a 'double free'.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `get_strings` overrides your initial `malloc`. A pointer value is a value. By equating it with something else, you *replaced* your `malloc` value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the code for `get_string()`, but you're overwriting `strings` with its return value which is wrong. The address you pass to `free()` must come from `malloc()`, and it seems you're violating that (in addition to losing the original returned address for your 10 bytes).

Assuming `get_string()` returns static storage (i.e. you don't need to free it) you can do this without involving `malloc()`.

If you really *want* to, something like this might work:

```
printf("What is your name?\n");
const char *name = get_string();
const size_t nlen = strlen(name);
char * const name_copy = malloc(nlen + 1);
if(name_copy != NULL)
{
  memcpy(name_copy, name, nlen + 1);
  printf("Hello %s (from my own memory!)\n", name_copy);
  free(name_copy);
}
```

This is rather convoluted but you get the idea.

Comment: The assumption is wrong: `get_string` returns memory that must be free'd by the caller. You might simple use `strdup` for the copying part. ;)

Answer (score 0):

First You have created a dynamic memory which will be pointed by ***strings**. But then you are pointing to the local string (from get_string() function) using ***strings** pointer. when you call free, program is trying delete local (stack) reference and throwing error.

To solve that error, the program should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{

char *strings = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);


printf("What is your name?\n");

//wait for use to type his/her name
strcpy(strings, get_string());       // Use strcpy instead of assigning


printf("Hello %s\n", strings);

free (strings);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`char *strings;`

- No need for new malloc as string returned from get_string() function is already on the heap, you just need to pick up pointer to first character. ([get_string() function reference](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_string))

strings = get_string();

printf("Hello %s\n", strings);

- After printing string you should free memory allocated for it, as it is stated in get_string() function reference

> Stores string on heap (via malloc); memory must be freed by caller to
>   avoid leak.

I think everything else is fine, try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

    int main (void)
    {
        char *strings;

        printf("What is your name?\n");

        //wait for use to type his/her name
        strings = get_string();

        printf("Hello %s\n", strings);

        free (strings);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I agree that `malloc` is not needed and causes memory leak. But how could this lead to error message "double free"?

Comment: @Gerhardh Problem is that compiler gets in trouble because he overwrites pointer  char *strings = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10); got from this malloc with get_string() return pointer value, so automatically he lost a pointer used to free what he malloced at first, and now it stays not freeded.

Comment: I know, but a memory leak is basically the opposite of what is normally indicated by a "double free or corrupt" error. The error message indicates that some memory is free'd twice or the memory boundaries were overwritten. The error message does not match with that memory leak. There must be something else. Which is rather strange given the short piece of code...

Comment: In that Q the OP did write past the end of allocated memory. That's clearly the cause there. In this Q here there is no writing done in that buffer.